# Adding image into a drupal 7 node using xmlrpc c#

Tags: c#, drupal, xml-rpc, image-uploading

i'm trying to add an image into a node. i searched the web but didn't find much. i think i need to upload the image first then add it into node so that's why i wrote some code to add the image into a folder(sites/all/default) but in vain. I'm getting some error in the XmlRpcClientProtocol.cs - "Could not write file to destination".

used file.create method.

```
     XmlRpcStruct file = new XmlRpcStruct();

        file.Add("file", encodedData);
        file.Add("filename", filename);
        file.Add("filepath", "sites/default/files/" + filename);
        file.Add("filesize", filestream.Length);
        file.Add("timestamp", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());

     drupal.FileSave(file);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

```py
with open(filepath + name_, 'rb') as f:
    img = base64.b64encode(f.read())
    size = os.path.getsize(filepath + name_)
    file = {'methodCall': 
             {'params': 
               {'param': 
                 {'struct': 
                   {'member': [
                     {'name': 'filesize', 'value':{'string': str(size)}}, 
                     {'name': 'filename', 'value':{'string': str(filepath + name_)}},
                     {'name': 'file', 'value':{'string': str(img)}}, 
                     {'name': 'filepath', 'value':{'string': 'public://product_image/'+str(name_)}}, 
                     ]
                   }
                 }
               }, 
               'methodName': 'file.create'
             }
           }   
    xml = dict2xml.dict2xml(file)
```